# Select difference between two row using one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have `table-A`, I want to select date range from `2016-06-25` and `2016-06-26` to find the difference in name.

Based on the pic the result should be like that:

```
2016-06-26  joe     40
```

I guess the query some thing like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `2g`
WHERE  'Date' between '2016-06-25' AND 'Date'   '2016-06-26'  
and (`name` != `name`)
```

[image]

Comment: seriously??? this where clause `and ( name != name )` will never return anything...ever!

Comment: How name!=name can be true in any way?

Comment: you can compare the ( age != age)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use My SQL query hope this work for you.

```
with x as   (select  *,k = COUNT(*)
            over(PARTITION BY Name,Age )
            from 2g)

select [Date]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Age] from x
where k <= 1 and Date between '2016-06-25' AND '2016-06-26'
```

[image]

Comment: i have several data for one month, i have to specify date, 'Date' between ('2016-06-25' AND '2016-06-26')   if there is a different age then i want to know.

Comment: Please review my updated answer..Hope it's help for you

Answer (score 0):

This where clause `and ( name != name )` will never return anything because  `name` will always be equal to `name`. You should do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 2g WHERE 'Date' between ('2016-06-25' AND '2016-06-26')  
AND count(name) = 1  
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: i have the age is different, the age have unique value. if there is different age between the two dates. then take it out.

Comment: add this in where clause `AND count(Age) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. I don't know about that this syntax work for mysql.

```
SELECT name FROM 2g
WHERE  'Date' between '2016-06-25' AND '2016-06-26'  
Group by Name 
Having count(Name) > 1
```

Comment: thanks for youe replay, what if i want to compare the age between the '2016-06-25' AND 'Date'   '2016-06-26' .  if the there is an different age between the two group sort it out  .                                                                                                                                   SELECT * FROM `2g` WHERE  'Date' between '2016-06-26' AND 'Date'   '2016-06-26'

Group by 'age' 
Having ('age') != ('age')

Comment: what is the meaning of two group and what will be the output you need for this.

Comment: i want to know of there is a new record, looking at the pic, (group 1): in date 25 there are 3 values the age 20,23,20. (group 2), there is 20, 23, 20,40 . i want the query select date and compare age >>> to find the 40